# T4 Template get table name of database

Tags: entity-framework-6, t4

There are times where I want to avoid using the EF because it takes longer to execute. As a result I want to create raw sql queries for performance purposes.

If I do `<#=entity.Name#>` it will give me the name of my model. For example it returns me `Contact`. The name of that table in the database is `Contacts` (note the s at the end). How can I get the actual table name instead of the model name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the EF T4 templates as I don't use them. EF has it's own Pluralization service.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Pluralization.EnglishPluralizationService

You can create an instance of this class and call Pluralize to get the Pluralized word. Probably not the most EF-pure way, but it will work. Maybe you can as for the EntitySet name or something if this feels dirty to you.